# TypeScript + RequireJs + other libraries (pdfjs)

Tags: typescript, requirejs, pdf.js

I am trying to integrate TypeScript in a fairly new project, with a few libraries. To support old browsers I decided to target `ES5`. I selected the module system `AMD`, since it is going to the frontend.

My `test.ts` file uses 3 libraries, which I import so TypeScript can use those and compiles fine:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as ko from "knockout";
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist";

export var MyViewModel = function (this: any, initUrl: string) {
  var self = this;
  self.UrlValue= ko.observable(initUrl);

  self.UrlValue.subscribe(function (newValue: string) {
    self.showPdfPreview(newValue);
  });

  self.showPdfPreview = function (url: string) {
    var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
    ...
  }
}
```

TypeScript compiles it to `test.js` with this import:

```
define(["require", "exports", "jquery", "knockout", "pdfjs-dist"], function (require, exports, $, ko, pdfjsLib) {
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

If I try to use it, I get this error: `TypeError: pdfjsLib is undefined`
**How do I fix this?**

RequireJs is basically configured like this:

```
<script src="~/lib/requirejs/dist/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "/",
        paths: {
            "jquery": "lib/jquery/dist/jquery-3.4.1",
            "knockout": "lib/knockout/dist/knockout-3.5.0",
            "pdfjs-dist": "lib/pdfjs/dist/build/pdf",
            "mytest": "js/test"
        },
        waitSeconds: 15
    });
    require(
        ["jquery", "knockout", "pdfjs-dist", "mytest"],
        function ($, ko, pdfjsLib, mytest) {
            var viewModel = new mytest.MyViewModel("@Model.Value");
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
    );
</script>
```

I am assuming that I have to require the pdfjsLib in `test.ts`. I cannot use require there just like that though, since TypeScript doesnt know the definition. Importing the library there does not work either, TS says its not a module. I feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The imports had to be changed for TypeScript targeting ES5. Also for some reason the pdfjs alias needs to be same as the path to the pdfjs module. In my case this is `pdfjs-dist/build/pdf`. So the imports look like this now:

```
//﻿/ <reference path="../TypeScript/@types/knockout/index.d.ts" />
import $ = require("jquery");
import pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf");
```

Using the reference is not recommended, but I havent found a working alternative yet.

The RequireJs configuration had to be changed to this:

```
<script src="~/lib/requirejs/dist/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "/",
        paths: {
            "jquery": "lib/jquery/dist/jquery-3.4.1",
            "knockout": "lib/knockout/dist/knockout-3.5.0",
            "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf": "lib/pdfjs/dist/build/pdf",
            'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker': "lib/pdfjs/dist/build/pdf.worker",
            "mytest": "js/test"
        },
        waitSeconds: 15
    });
    require(
        ["knockout", "mytest"],
        function (ko, mytest) {
            var viewModel = new mytest.MyViewModel("@Model.Value");
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
    );
</script>
```